# What piece of furniture?

Tags: riddle

What piece of furniture can any mammal make, without tools?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more of a joke than a riddle.

Comment: A riddle cannot be a joke as well?  I didn't know the two definitions are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Yes, there is overlap between jokes and riddles. In general, puzzles on this site should strive for quality much higher than poop and fart jokes.

Comment: I wrote a new riddle of higher quality.  I couldn't resist posting this one that I thought of when I was a child.  Admittedly, this is low-brow humor, but the new one is not.

Comment: If it had made more of a play on the anagram of _tools_ then I could have been interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would it be a

> stool ? (as in the result of defecation)

Comment: You, sir, are correct.  Sometimes thinking dirty can be a good thing.  :-)